# I just don't understand threads in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ipc

Okay, so, here's the deal.

I'm currently writing a small chat messaging simulation / project using SysV IPC, and I use Qt for my client app. What I want is a background thread that would wait on a message queue and send a signal to a GUI thread whenever a new message comes. I have attempted to write the code using QThread inheritance, but it doesn't seem to work, the messages are not shown, and I think I'm missing something here.

As for the code:
ipcEventListener.h:

```
class IPCEventListener : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    IPCEventListener();
    void run();
    messageWrapper mw;
signals:
    void sendChatMsg(MSG_CHAT_MESSAGE cm);
};
```

ipcEventListener.cpp

```
IPCEventListener::IPCEventListener()
{

}
void IPCEventListener::run()
{
        mutex.lock();
        int n = msgrcv(myQueueId, &mw, sizeof(mw)-sizeof(long), 0, IPC_NOWAIT);
        mutex.unlock();
        if (n>0)
        {
            snip...
            else if (mw.resp.type == MESSAGE)
            {
                emit sendChatMsg(mw.chatMsg);
            }
        }
    exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    listener = new IPCEventListener(this);
    connect(this->listener, SIGNAL(sendChatMsg(MSG_CHAT_MESSAGE)), this, SLOT(message_received(MSG_CHAT_MESSAGE)));
    connect(this->ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
    listener->start();
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Client");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Room");
}
void MainWindow::message_received(MSG_CHAT_MESSAGE cm)
{
    QString formattedMessage = "";
    formattedMessage.append("[");
    formattedMessage.append(cm.send_time);
    formattedMessage.append("] ");
    if (cm.msg_type == PRIVATE) formattedMessage.append("[PRIV:] ");
    formattedMessage.append(cm.sender);
    formattedMessage.append(": ");
    formattedMessage.append(cm.message);
    formattedMessage.append("\n");
    ui->textEdit->append(formattedMessage);
}
```

What am I missing?

(PS: I know the code probably breaks about a hundred thousand of code conventions, but the deadline is pretty soon and I have to resort to kludges. It's just a school project, though).

Comment: Did you declare `MainWindow::message_received` as a slot?

Comment: Yes, it's in the `private slots:` section in a header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logical error in your code. You treat void IPCEventListener::run() as a method which is in a loop and is executing again ang again ang again but it's not. QThread::run() is method where you only initialize your thread and execute exec() function, to start event loop. It means that in current version of your application, you try to receive message just once and then your thread is just waiting for some events, without doing anything with them.

So what you need is an inifite loop in which you will try to receive messages. And don't forget to stop this loop while program closing.